# Неверно приходят данные пользовательского параметра в Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

У меня есть следующий код Google Analytics

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-********-*', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true });
      ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
      ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
      ga('require', 'linker');
      ga('linker:autoLink', ['site.com', 'site.biz']);
      if (typeof GLOBAL !== 'undefined' && GLOBAL.hashId) {
          ga('set', '&uid', GLOBAL.hashId.toString());
          ga('set', 'dimension1', GLOBAL.hashId.toString());
      }
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

dimension1 это мой пользовательский параметр. в него записывается значение когда юзер авторизован

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    GLOBAL.hashId = тут_число;
    //другие переменные
</script>
```

Пользовательский параметр определен на обласить видимости - пользователь.
При открытии отчета, например, демографические данные >> возраст и добавив мой пользовательский параметр Lead Hash ID я вижу что данных мало и некоторые айди совпадают http://prntscr.com/htenyy .
Подскажите, где закралась ошибка?

Comment: Ваш код действительно так выглядит? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/764561/edit) и выделите кодом `<Ctrl-K>`.

Comment: Сделала. Почему то пропал тег <script>, а так да, действительно так выглядит.